# how do I import cx_Oracle to AWS Lambda python 3.6 for windows os

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, cx-oracle

We have tried zipping the cx_Oracle and Oracle instant client with the .py file  and uploaded it to AWS Lambda, it says no module named cx_Oracle exists, can someone please help us with the process? We are trying to connect to an Oracle DB for making an Alexa skill set.

Comment: Are you using any framework for deployment, like [serverless](https://serverless.com) or [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model)? At least for serverless there are plugins that can help you with stuff like that (especially when the packages you need have binary dependencies, which most of the python db APIs have).

Comment: We are not using any framework, the step we have followed are below:       
1) imported the cx_Oracle in the virtualenv using pip. 2) added oracle instant client 3)added the .py file . 4) ziped these into 1 file and deployed to Lambda

Comment: For future readers, the latest Oracle DB driver for Python doesn't necessarily need Instant Client, which makes deployment easier.  The driver got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb, see https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/